# migrate from webpack to vite with vuejs for chrome extension project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vite

I am working on a chrome extension using vuejs currently i have a ready project to start with but it is with webpack.

In the webpack I have multi-entry points some of which lead to generating HTML files and others with javascript only.

with webpack it is clear what is the inputs and how they will be as output in Vite i tried but there is a lot of plugins outdated that work with vuejs 3

this link contains the project
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-v83gga

my webpack file is :

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

// Generate pages object
const pages = {};

function getEntryFile(entryPath) {
  let files = fs.readdirSync(entryPath);
  return files;
}

const chromeName = getEntryFile(path.resolve(`src/entry`));

function getFileExtension(filename) {
  return /[.]/.exec(filename) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(filename)[0] : undefined;
}
chromeName.forEach((name) => {
  const fileExtension = getFileExtension(name);
  const fileName = name.replace("." + fileExtension, "");
  pages[fileName] = {
    entry: `src/entry/${name}`,
    template: "public/index.html",
    filename: `${fileName}.html`,
  };
});

const isDevMode = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";

module.exports = {
  pages,
  filenameHashing: false,
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.plugin("copy").use(require("copy-webpack-plugin"), [
      {
        patterns: [
          {
            from: path.resolve(`src/manifest.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.json`),
            to: `${path.resolve("dist")}/manifest.json`,
          },
          {
            from: path.resolve(`public/`),
            to: `${path.resolve("dist")}/`,
          },
        ],
      },
    ]);
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      filename: `[name].js`,
      chunkFilename: `[name].js`,
    },
    devtool: isDevMode ? "inline-source-map" : false,
  },
  css: {
    extract: false, // Make sure the css is the same
  },
};
```

Comment: This project was created by vue-cli-plugin-chrome-extension-cli for more info check this link 
https://github.com/sanyu1225/vue-cli-plugin-chrome-extension-cli

Comment: are you just trying to migrate a vuejs (which version) build environment (vue-cli to vite) or are you also trying to upgrade vue2 to vue3? You say you've tried, but haven't shown any vite config at all - your "project" you link to doesn't even have a `main.js`

Comment: I am building a chrome extension which has a different structure as an output we need these files, manifest.json, popup.html, options.html, content-script.js, and background.js, i want to build all of those files using a vuejs project so i moved the removed the main.js and i have another 4(similar files to main.js)which is the new entry point for the webpack to work on which will generate the 5 files that i need including the manifest.json, in webpack i can set what is entry points even if it is html file or js files and what is the output of it, i want to convert that to be used with the vite

Comment: Don't start with vue-cli + vue2 base code you got from some random website then try to convert it to vite + vue3 ... start by scaffolding a vite + vue3 application, and add your code to that

Comment: it is different as i am talking about the vite.config.json file and how to handle it, finally, i found out that for the HTML file vite accept multiple entry but if I have to generate with the HTML a js file only I have to create another vite.config file specific for the js file

Comment: huh? webpack/vue-cli doesn't have a vite.config.json file

Comment: this is in the vite.config.js file is in the vite project not in the webpack this is what i meant thank you @JaromandaX

Comment: but you said "my webpack file is"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally find out a solution for it as a pre-build template by vitesse written with typescript

https://github.com/antfu/vitesse-webext

in short answer if you want to have multiple entries of HTML files you can add them to the original vite.config.js file

regarding the content.ts file, it needs a different vite.config.content.ts file and we have to call it when we build the project like this

```
vite build && vite build --config vite.config.content.ts
```

regarding the vite.config.ts file, the code will be like this written in typescript

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />

import { dirname, relative } from 'path'
import type { UserConfig } from 'vite'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import Icons from 'unplugin-icons/vite'
import IconsResolver from 'unplugin-icons/resolver'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import WindiCSS from 'vite-plugin-windicss'
import windiConfig from './windi.config'
import { isDev, port, r } from './scripts/utils'

export const sharedConfig: UserConfig = {
  root: r('src'),
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~/': `${r('src')}/`,
    },
  },
  define: {
    __DEV__: isDev,
  },
  plugins: [
    Vue(),

    AutoImport({
      imports: [
        'vue',
        {
          'webextension-polyfill': [
            ['*', 'browser'],
          ],
        },
      ],
      dts: r('src/auto-imports.d.ts'),
    }),

    // https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components
    Components({
      dirs: [r('src/components')],
      // generate `components.d.ts` for ts support with Volar
      dts: r('src/components.d.ts'),
      resolvers: [
        // auto import icons
        IconsResolver({
          componentPrefix: '',
        }),
      ],
    }),

    // https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-icons
    Icons(),

    // rewrite assets to use relative path
    {
      name: 'assets-rewrite',
      enforce: 'post',
      apply: 'build',
      transformIndexHtml(html, { path }) {
        return html.replace(/"\/assets\//g, `"${relative(dirname(path), '/assets')}/`)
      },
    },
  ],
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: [
      'vue',
      '@vueuse/core',
      'webextension-polyfill',
    ],
    exclude: [
      'vue-demi',
    ],
  },
}

export default defineConfig(({ command }) => ({
  ...sharedConfig,
  base: command === 'serve' ? `http://localhost:${port}/` : '/dist/',
  server: {
    port,
    hmr: {
      host: 'localhost',
    },
  },
  build: {
    outDir: r('extension/dist'),
    emptyOutDir: false,
    sourcemap: isDev ? 'inline' : false,
    // https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/program_policies/#:~:text=Code%20Readability%20Requirements
    terserOptions: {
      mangle: false,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        background: r('src/background/index.html'),
        options: r('src/options/index.html'),
        popup: r('src/popup/index.html'),
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    ...sharedConfig.plugins!,

    // https://github.com/antfu/vite-plugin-windicss
    WindiCSS({
      config: windiConfig,
    }),
  ],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
  },
}))
```

the important part of it is this

vite.config.ts

```
...
build: {
    outDir: r('extension/dist'),
    emptyOutDir: false,
    sourcemap: isDev ? 'inline' : false,
    // https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/program_policies/#:~:text=Code%20Readability%20Requirements
    terserOptions: {
      mangle: false,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        background: r('src/background/index.html'),
        options: r('src/options/index.html'),
        popup: r('src/popup/index.html'),
      },
    },
  },
...
```

Thank you to anyone who tried to help and I hope this will be helpful to others

Regards